# Subgraph isomorphism to SAT

Tags: graph, np, isomorphism, satisfiability

The Subgraph Isomorphism (SI) problem is a computational task in which two graphs G and H are given as input, and one must determine whether G contains a subgraph that is isomorphic to H.

This is a **NP-Complete problem** .

I want to know its relation with the SAT problem.
 In particular, I want  instances of this problem can be solved throughout SAT Solver(like [miniSAT](http://minisat.se/)).I need an alorithm  which can do a mapping from SI to SAT problem in polynomial time and then SAT assignment can be used to find a mapping from nodes of G to nodes of H .

Any idea ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `SAT` encoding for the *Graph Isomorphism* problem is described in the [SAT 2013](http://sat2013.cs.helsinki.fi/) paper "[On the Resolution Complexity of Graph non-Isomorphism](http://sat2013.cs.helsinki.fi/slides/SAT2013-toran.pdf)".

Minisat is one of the best-known SAT solvers, but it has several successors which are probably faster and have a higher success rate. Try [Cryptominisat](http://www.msoos.org/cryptominisat2/) (version 2.9.5 seems to be faster than version 3; it supports parallel threads), [Riss3g](http://tools.computational-logic.org/content/riss3g.php) or [Clasp](http://www.cs.uni-potsdam.de/clasp/).